# Weird IF THAN not working with Requested data from URL text problem

Tags: objective-c, iphone

Hey all, i am checking for an internet connection by checking for a file on my server. The file only has the word LIVE displayed on the page. No HTML or anything else is there, just the word LIVE.

When i run this code, i do get the NSLog as saying "LIVE" but once i go to check it with the IF statement, it fails and i just do not know why???

```
NSString* myFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxx.com/iPodTouchPing.html"];
NSString* myFileURLString = [myFile stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *myFileData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myFileURLString]];
NSString *returnedMyFileContents=[[[NSString alloc] initWithData:myFileData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@", returnedMyFileContents);

if (returnedMyFileContents == @"LIVE") {
  NSLog(@"LIVE!");
}else{
  NSLog(@"Not Live");
}
```

What am i doing wrong? I can not seem to find the reason??

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare strings like that in Objective C - you're just comparing their *addresses*, not their contents. Change your code to this:

```
if ([returnedMyFileContents isEqualToString:@"LIVE"]) {
  NSLog(@"LIVE!");
} else {
  NSLog(@"Not Live");
}
```